# Возможно ли изменить значение ключа в словаре?

Tags: python, словари, dict

Возможно ли, не создавая новых элементов словаря, изменить значение какого-либо из его ключей?
Вопрос чисто теоретический, на практике такой необходимости у меня не возникало.
Интересует в первую очередь Python 3.6+

Comment: Если вам помог ответ, примите его пожалуйста.

Comment: почитайте про хэш-таблицы - расширьте видение происходящего при работе со словарями

Comment: @EugeneDennis, спасибо, почитал. Но пока остаётся недопонимание: в качестве ключа словаря можно использовать пользовательский объект, который в общем случае изменяем (mutable), как при этом не меняется хэш-значение?

Comment: пользовательский объект может иметь методы `__hash__()` или `__eq__`, `__cmp__` , тогда его можно будет использовать в качестве ключа, по умолчанию пользовательский класс можно использовать в качестве словаря, но там берётся `self.id`, а он у двух одинаковых классов разный, поэтому для использования это мало где пригодиться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Технически поменять ключ вы не можете, поэтому есть 2 варианта:

1. первый

   ```
   dictionary[new_key] = dictionary[old_key]
   del dictionary[old_key]
   ```
2. второй

   ```
   dictionary[new_key] = dictionary.pop(old_key)
   ```

Однако стоит учитывать что если ключа не будет в словаре, то может быть выброшено исключение, если старый ключ не найден:

```
>>> dictionary = { 1: 'one', 2:'two', 3:'three' }
>>> dictionary['ONE'] = dictionary.pop(1)
>>> dictionary
{2: 'two', 3: 'three', 'ONE': 'one'}
>>> dictionary['ONE'] = dictionary.pop(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 1
```

Comment: @Andrey Верно. Просто что-то не то написал.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Axenow. Но предложенные вами варианты мне уже известны и приводились на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary). Я хотел понять принципиальную возможность **изменения** ключей в словаре, так как в документации не говорится, что ключи должны быть immutable, а только hashable (так как в dict используются hash-таблицы?)